# GAE/GWT server side data inconsistent / not persisting between instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, persistence

I'm writing a game app on GAE with GWT/Java and am having a issues with server-side persistent data.
Players are polling using RPC for active games and game states, all being stores on the server. Sometimes client polling fails to find game instances that I know should exist. This only happens when I deploy to google appspot, locally everything is fine.

I understand this could be to do with how appspot is a clouded service and that it can spawn and use a new instance of my servlet at any point, and the existing data is not persisting between instances.

Single games only last a minute or two and data will change rapidly, (multiple times a second) so what is the best way to ensure that RPC calls to different instances will use the same server-side data?

I have had a look at the DataStore API and it seems to be database like storage which i'm guessing will be way too slow for what I need. Also Memcache can be flushed at any point so that's not useful.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues here: persisting data between requests and polling data from clients.

1. When you have a distributed servlet environment (such as GAE) you can not make request to one instance, save data to memory and expect that data is available on other instances. This is true for GAE and any other servlet environment where you have multiple servers.

   So to you need to save data to some shared storage: Datastore is costly, persistent, reliable and slow. Memcache is fast, free, but non-reliable. Usually we use a combination of both. Some libraries even transparently combine both: [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache), [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Caching).

   On GAE there is also a third option to have semi-persisted shared data: [backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview). Those are always-on instances, where you control startup/shutdown.
2. Data polling: if you have multiple clients waiting for updates, it's best not to use polling. Polling will make a lot of unnecessary requests (data did not change on server) and there will still be a minimum delay (since you poll at some interval). Instead of polling you use push via [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/). There are even GWT libs for it: [gwt-gae-channel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/), [gwt-channel-api](https://github.com/eirikb/gwt-channel-api).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You did not design your game to run on App Engine.

You sound like you've already answered your own question.  You understand that data is not persisted across instances.  The two mechanisms for persisting data on the server side are memcache and the datastore, but you also understand the limitations of these.  You need to architect your game around this.

If you're not using memcache or the datastore, how are you persisting your data (my best guess is that you aren't actually persisting it).  From the vague details, you have not architected your game to be able to run across multiple instances, which is essential for any app running on App Engine.  It's a basic design principle that you don't know which instance any HTTP request will hit.  You have to rearchitect to use the datastore + memcache.

If you want to use a single server, you can use backends, which behave like single servers that stick around (if you limit it to one instance).  Frankly though, because of the cost, you're better off with Amazon or Rackspace if you go this route.  You will also have to deal with scaling on your own - ie if a game is running on a particular server instance, you need to build a way such that playing the game consistently hits that instance.

Comment: You are correct in saying I am not persisting the data, the question is essentially how to persist it across multiple instances with my kind of requirements, if possible.

Comment: The info you've provided so far is too vague for me to give you any more real feedback.  I would not build a realtime FPS or RTS game on top of app engine, it just seems like the wrong architcture for that.  You will have to use the datastore ane memcache for performance.  The limitation on write frequency and consistency model would make it very difficult, plus you'd get perf hiccups if you get significant memcache faults and you have to run to the datastore.

I would recommend another server architecture for a realtime game.

Comment: If you really want to use App Engine and are willing to think outside the box, you could potentially design your game as a peer-to-peer system and only use app engine for stuff like storing score, or redesign your game as a turn-based game with less in terms of server side perf requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can deploy GWT applications without GAE, see this explanation:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideRPCDeployment

You may want to ask yourself: Will your application ever NEED multiple server instances or GAE-specific features?

If so, then I agree with Peter Knego's reply regarding memcache etc.

If not, then you might be able to work around your problem by choosing a different hosting option (other than GAE). Particularly one that lets you work with just a single instance. You could then indeed simply manage all your game data in server memory, like I understand you have been doing so far.

If this solution suits your purpose, then all you need to do is find a suitable hosting provider. This may well be a cloud-based PaaS offer, provided that they let you put a *hard* limit (unlike with GAE) on the number of server instances, and that it goes as low as one. For example, Heroku *(currently)* lets you do that, as far as I understand, and apparently it's suitable for GWT applications, according to this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583493/2237986

Note that the above solution involves a bit of fiddling and I don't know your needs well enough to make a strong recommendation. There may be easier and better solutions for what you're trying to do. In particular, have a look at non-cloud-based hosting options and server architectures that are optimized for highly time-critical, real-time multiplayer gaming.

Hope this helps! Keep us posted on your progress.